# Conditional renaming of multiple files from multiple subfolders based on a list of prefix

Tags: python, dictionary, os.walk

I have a path with multiple subfolders, and files with different extensions.
Now, I made different lists for each filetypes (files of different extensions)

```
path='/user/path/output'
```

Defining lists for each file extensions

```
png         =list()
txt         =list()
```

Then populating my lists with files,

```
 import os
 for (dirpath,dirname,filenames) in os.walk(path):
     txt +=[os.path.join(dirpath,file) for file in filenames if file.endswith("txt") ]
     png +=[os.path.join(dirpath,file) for file in filenames if file.endswith("png") ]
```

Now the lists looks as following,

```
print(txt)
['/user/path/output/SAP.txt','/user/path/output/LUF.txt']
```

And the `png`

```
['/user/path/output/SAP-tcga-01_scs.png','/user/path/output/LUF-tcga-01_scs.png']
```

Here, I have a list of prefixes. These prefixes need to be appended to the above lists of filenames. Hence, I created a dictionary, with the sample name as values and prefix as their keys.
The first part of the list suffix: is filename and the secound part is suffix.  The list suffix must correctly, append to the right filename. That is the condition here.

```
suffix  =["SAP_xz","LUF_df"]
prefix_for_files={value.split('_')[0]:value for value in suffix}
```

Then, I have two list of filenames with paths and a dictionary of the prefix needed to be appended for each files within 2 lists.

To do this I wrote a for loop, like this,

```
  for value,ids in prefix_for_files.items():
        sample_prefix=ids.split('_')[1]
```

Finally, I need to read each items in the lists (`txt` and `png`) and see if the values in the `prefix_for_files` matches to the basename of filenames in  the `lists`.

I am stuck here, any sort of suggestions are much appreciated.

At the end I need the list of files as, for example, for `png` files,

```
 /user/path/output/SAP_xz.png
/user/path/output/LUF_df.png
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `glob.glob`

```
import glob
import os

types = ('*.png', '*.txt') # Stuff to search for
files = []
for ftype in types:
    files.extend(glob.glob('/home/chris/dev/output/**/{}'.format(ftype), recursive=True))    

# For me this would produce
# ['/home/chris/dev/output/blank.txt',
# '/home/chris/dev/output/b.png',
# '/home/chris/dev/output/t.png',
# '/home/chris/dev/output/f2/okay.png',
# '/home/chris/dev/output/f1/hello.png',
# '/home/chris/dev/output/f1/goodbye.png']
```

Then if you need anything with the absolute path (if this isn't your absolute path already), you can do this:

```
for f in files:
    abspath = os.path.abspath(f)
    # Rename/delete/etc with abspath
```

Comment: Thank you! The problem, the issue is not that straight forward I need a `if condition` before renaming each case with the `suffix `. The renaming should be based on the `suffix  =["SAP_xz","LUF_df"]` information. I mean I need to take the suffix from the list `suffix` that is, `xz` and `df` and append to files in the `path` which has names `SAP` and `LUF`.